# Check duplicate values on specific condition

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table (product attributes) that has these columns:

```
product_attribute_id
attribute_term_id
attribute_id
product_id
```

attribute_term_id and attribute_id is a combination, such as this (on the term table):

```
attribute_term_id  attribute_id  term
17252              40            Integrated Modem 56K
693363             40            Info Not Available
41117              40            None
```

There are multiple products with pair entries attribute_term_id and attribute_id and we recently introduced a condition where we cannot have a product with this combination for example:

```
693363             40            Info Not Available
41117              40            None
```

or this:

```
17252              40            Integrated Modem 56K
41117              40            None
```

How can we check this in a simple way? It basically check if a product has an attribute pair with term = 'None' AND the same product has another attribute pair under the same attribute_id (whichever)

Comment: I'm lost.  Where does `term` come from?  What does the initial table have to do with the question?

Comment: I just edited my question, the term comes form the term table

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `exists`,I assume you have term column in that table

```
  select t1.*, 
 case when exists( select 1 from product_attributes  t2 where t1.attribute_id=t2.attribute_id and t2.term in ('None','Info Not Available')
 ) then 'write_flag' else 'enotherflag' end 
  from product attributes) t1
```

Comment: Thanks, this wouldn't cover the other attributes, such as 'Modem' etc, we have plenty